# The system cannot find the file specified - Process - C# Winform 32 bit application

Tags: wpf, winforms

```
var proc = new Process();
var application = RegistryEx.GetApplicationFromExtension(Path.GetExtension(fileName)); 
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(@application); 
info.Arguments = @fileName;
proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
Here @application - C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe
Filename - E:\ProjectSM\_scripts\xappl\Prod\Architectural\949133621473206472\local-test-pdf.pdf
```

Above error occurs when application information is fetched from registry for file extension. From visual studio above code works fine, but when creating exe the above error occurs from the application. I have entered log to verify this and came to know that application can find file but not application. My application is 32 bit.

Comment: You could just skip searching for the application and just start a process with the FileName only. That would let the OS figure out what application to use. It might be slower though

Comment: I have done same before, but when .pdf file is selected to open with google chrome or any other application which user has installed on his machine, than it is throwing error.

Comment: What is the path of @filename? Does it have a path or it's just a file name in your Debug/Release directory? Do you really need `.WaitForExit()`? Also, as @GuidoG said, if you need to launch the default application, you can just execute the file (with a path attached to it).

Comment: Filename - E:\ProjectSM\_scripts\xappl\Prod\Architectural\949133621473206472\local-test-pdf.pdf. Application - C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe. Full path in debug and release. In debug i can find application and in release it does not work.

Comment: How do you reach `\Program Files`? With a `SpecialFolder`? Because, if you target `x86`, the returned path for `Program Files` is `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Yes target is x86 so getting program files from RegistryEx.GetApplicationFromExtension

Comment: I don't know how `RegistryEx.GetApplicationFromExtension()` works (I assume it's using `AssocQueryString()`). I also don't see where you're passing the file name as argument. It should be `var info = new ProcessStartInfo(@application, fileName);`. The file name is the `.Argument` parameter of your `ProcessStartInfo`.  Setup a control at run-time, where you can output the actual Application path before passing it to the Process. This code, with correct paths and Argument parts, should work as intended.

Comment: A 32 bit application has no access to "C:\Program Files", but only "C:\Program Files (x86)". That's part of the WOW64 redirection.

Comment: @Lex Li  It's not requesting to access the process. It's delegating the Shell to run a program.

Comment: @Jimi if you delegate to the 32 bit shell, it has the same problem.

Comment: @Lex Li  It's not a Console program. The Shell is the OS Shell. Unless you're referring to the Registry access. That will have differents results based on the Process bitness.